# R how to control spacing of colour bar/legend

Tags: r, legend, colorbar, r-raster

I'd like to plot a map of chlorophyll concentration, but the values are dispersed in such a way that the legend becomes unreadable (see picture)

[image: chl_a]

So I am trying to control the spacing of the colours in the colour bar/legend. I'd like to get it evenly spaced (while keeping the uneven breaks on the map itself).

The the example below is much simplified and is for a raster plot, but the same goes for image.plot.

```
library(raster)    
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=4)
r[] <- 1:20
plot(r, breaks = c(0,1,2,3,5,10,20), col = rainbow(6))
```

I thought about converting the data to log values, but that doesn't give me a satisfying result. So any help with the legend is much appreciated.

Comment: Can't your just split the range of values in 'r' into deciles and use that for the colorRamp that creates the palette passed to the 'col' argument?

Comment: Thanks, that could be a way to work around the problem, but I rather stay in control of the breaks in 'r' and find a solution to control the legend spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ugly, but you can use `plot` for the map and `image.plot` for your legend. You will need to add the labels of your custom breaks to the position of the equally spaced breaks.

Plot map without legend:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=4)
r[] <- 1:20
my_breaks = c(0,1,2,3,5,10,20)
n = 6
my_col    = rainbow(n)
plot(r, breaks = my_breaks, col = my_col, legend = FALSE, zlim=c(0,20))
```

The default breaks will be equally spaced from 0 to 20:

```
def_breaks = seq(0,20,length.out=(n+1))
```

Add legend using `image.plot` from the `fields` package, placing custom break labels at default break positions:

```
library(fields)
image.plot(r, zlim = c(0,20), 
           legend.only = TRUE, 
           col = my_col,
           axis.args = list(at = def_breaks, labels = my_breaks))
```