# How to adjust legend spacing in R raster plots

Tags: r, plot, raster

I have a rather straightforward question. For example:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(lattice)
a<-raster(matrix(rep(c(1:5,50,100)),7,7))
plot.new()
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
sbreak<-c(1,2,3,4,5,50,100)
col.l <- colorRampPalette(c('darkblue','blue','deepskyblue','cyan','orange','darkred'))(100)
print(levelplot(a,margin=FALSE,col.regions=col.l,at=sbreak,par.settings=list(layout.heights=list(xlab.key.padding=2),col=col.l)))
```

I only care about the range from 1 to 5, but have to plot outliers up to 100. The plot itself is fine, but I can hardly see the range of 1-5 in the legend. I'd like to have equal space between the breaks I specified (1,2,3,4,5,50,100). 
[image]

**************update*******************
I've just solved the problem, there's an easy way to do this rather than plotting legend separately:
`sbreak1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,50,100)`
`sbreak2<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`
`legendbreak<-c('<1','2','3','4','5','50','100')`
`col.l <-colorRampPalette(c('darkblue','blue','deepskyblue','cyan','orange','darkred'))(1‌​‌​00)`
`print(levelplot(a,margin=FALSE,col.regions=col.l,at=sbreak1,par.settings=lis‌​t(la‌​yout.heights=list(xlab.key.padding=2),col=col.l),colorkey=list(at=sbreak2,l‌​abels=‌​legendbreak,col=col.l))`

The key is to cheat the legend with separate setting. Thanks for the guidance

Comment: Perhaps you can use the answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061492/r-how-to-control-spacing-of-colour-bar-legend/19157744#19157744) similar question. The trick is to plot map and legend separately and placing custom tick labels.

Comment: @koekenbakker, thanks a lot for the guidance. Just found an easy way to deal with it. OP has been updated.

Comment: You can post your update as an answer to this question yourself, would be very useful!

Comment: There are some examples in the [rasterVis FAQs](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#sec-1).